# Assigning a value to the divergent sum of the factorial

Tags: definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, factorial, divergent-series

As seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832501/the-divergent-sum-of-alternating-factorials), it is possible to assign a value to the alternating factorial series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nn!\approx0.596$$

I am interested in the non-alternating series.  Here is my attempt:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}dx$$

However, there is a singularity at $x=1$, so I cannot proceed any further with this method.

I am wondering if someone could finish the last line or provide insight into a possible other method to solving this problem.

Comment: I forgot the tag for assigning values to divergent integrals, which may be helpful here if someone could...

Comment: The method you are using works. The presence of a singularity simply illustrates that your series (viewed as a complex function) has a branch cut. The singularity at x=1 introduces a branch cut equal to $\frac{e}{\pi} i$.

Comment: It converges in the $p$-adic numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interpret this as principal value:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} (\int_0^{1-\epsilon} + \int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty) \frac{e^{-t}}{1-t} dt$$   So the integral evaluates to something like 0.6971796...

Comment: the value of the integral depends upon the regularization that you are using.

Comment: indeed if you use an asymmetric regularization $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} (\int_0^{1-\epsilon} + \int_{1+e^2}^\infty) \frac{e^{-t}}{1-t} dt \to -\infty$

Comment: True, so the type of regularisation should come from somewhere... (possible from the sleeves)

Comment: @FrancescoAlem. Hm, is there even any reason to use asymmetric regularizations?  It seems symmetric regularizing is much more accepted.

Comment: it's just to point out that you can get any value just by changing the way $\epsilon \to 0$,

Comment: For Borel summation is there a standard way to take the limit, or a "natural" way to take the limit?

Answer (score 1):

This question could use a little more attention. I believe the standard value for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n! = -e^{-1}\text{Ei}_1\left( {-1} \right)$ see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428577/evaluating-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-n-xn-and-inverse-variable-fraction) where it is shown that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!x^n = -\frac{1}{x} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} \text{Ei}_1 \left( {-\frac{1}{x}} \right) $$

Setting $x=1$ gives you the desired result. Numerically this appears to be about 0.0807 as per [here](https://wolframalpha.com/input?i=-e%5E%28-1%29Ei%28-1%29)

Comment: The answer you're drawing your result from has a sign mistake-- we should have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! x^n = \frac{1}{x} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} Ei_1\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. 

In that case, we obtain 0.6971... as the other answer obtain (i.e. $\frac{Ei_1(1)}{e}$), and now we obtain the correct result of $e Ei_1(-1)=0.596...$ for the alternating series.

Comment: Just waiting to confirm with the answerer there. Once they ack i will then update this answer  accordingly :) nice catch

Comment: The proposed alternate function is not continuous at $x=0$, and does not satisfy the formal DE used in https://mathoverflow.net/a/428595/454  But if we use $\operatorname{Ei}$ and not $\operatorname{Ei}_1$, then it agrees with mine for $<0$ (the alternating case), and has better properties than mine for $x>0$.  I guess it is a different analytic continuation of the $x<0$ case.