# Ramanujan summation of alternating factorials: why is it $0.596...$?

Tags: summation, factorial, ramanujan-summation

I was reading Ramanujan's letter to Hardy and came across this identity:
$$0!-1!+2!-3!+...=0.596...$$
Ramanujan didn't give the exact value of that constant, but it is the [Euler-Gompertz constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_constant?wprov=sfla1), as stated in the comments.
This seems nonsensical, but in fact, this makes sense, if we study some methods of "forcing divergents to converge". For example, $1+2+3+....$ is $-1/12$ because $\zeta(-1)$ is $-1/12$. But I can't prove why this is true. So my question is:

- How can this be proved?

Sorry if this question is stupid.

Comment: This is the Euler-Gompertz constant. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_1_%2B_2_%E2%88%92_6_%2B_24_%E2%88%92_120_%2B_... and https://oeis.org/A073003

Comment: @player3236 wow! This is surprising. Thank you very much.

Comment: [This related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832501/) could also be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a little bit buried in one of the formulas in the Wikipedia article for the [Euler-Gompertz constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_constant):

$$G = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1 + x} \, dx.$$

This integral can be expanded formally into a divergent series as follows. We have

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1 + x} \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n x^n e^{-x} \, dx "=" \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} \, dx$$

(the equal sign being in quotes because the exchange of sum and integral here is not actually justified) and the integral defining the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) gives

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} \, dx = n!.$$

This can be proven pretty straightforwardly by induction on $n$ using integration by parts, and there is also a cute generating function proof. So, formally, we get $G "=" \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n n!$. (I consider it quite misleading to use ordinary equality to talk about sums of divergent series.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple answer!

Comment: The exchange of integration and summation is to be blamed here as the uniform convergence has not been invoked here.