# Examples of functions with 0 radius of convergence analytically continued

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-continuation

Does anyone know of any examples of functions that can be analytically continued (or continued using another method), and have a radius of convergence of zero? I have read before that something like conformal mapping can be used to continue functions with a 0 radius of convergence, but I have been unable to find any specific examples. I would appreciate it if anyone could share any examples or links to examples of functions that fit the criteria.

Update: I've found a few examples to get started with. Somos gave a link that shows that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nn!x^n$$
can be continued to
$$e^{\frac{1}{x}}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{t}}}{t}dt$$
as shown in the graph below
[image]
The other example I found is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{l}\left(2l+2\right)^{k}}{\left(2l+1\right)!}\right)x^{k}$ can be continued to
$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t} e^{st}\sin(e^{st})dt$$

Comment: I can't make any sense of the request. The original power series is analytic _nowhere_, so what could an "analytic continuation" even mean?

Comment: Question is vague (previous comment).  What about a function with a pole at zero?

Comment: @davidcullrich: is there a difference between a function that is analytic nowhere and one which is analytic only at zero?

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article [Divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) helpful.

Comment: Also the [MSE question 1832501](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1832501/) "The divergent sum of alternating factorials" is directly relevant.

Comment: @Somos This is a great link, I will check it out

Comment: @abiessu - yes there is a difference. There are many functions that are analytic nowhere, but there are no functions that are analytic at a single point., "Analytic" means having a positive radius of convergence on its power series about every point in the domain, and that those power series must also converge to the function.