# Divergent sum of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\alpha n\right)!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, divergent-series

EDIT: I've rephrased the question

I'm interested in ways to formally sum the series $$s=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\alpha n\right)!$$

When $\alpha$ < 1, this series can be calculated using Borel summation.

Using Borel summation we get $s = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(\alpha n\right)!\left(t\right)^{n}}{n!}\right)dt$. To have this value actually converge, we need to be careful of how fast each of the infinities grow. We need to ensure in the expression $\int_{0}^{N_0}e^{-t}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(\alpha n\right)!\left(t\right)^{n}}{n!}\right)dt$ that $N_0$ is much smaller than $N$.

But for $\alpha$ >1, Borel summation doesn't work, since $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left(\alpha n\right)!}{\left(n\right)!}t^n = \infty$.

Using another method, I have managed to get some results for ways to sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\alpha n\right)! x^n$, but I'm not sure if these results are valid. I'm hoping to see a solution to these sums with another method to check my answers. I'm thinking it's potentially possible to find the value of this sum using a differential equation approach, a stronger form of Borel summation, or possibly using Ramanujan summation, but I'm unfamiliar with these approaches.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The terms do not go to $0$, so what do you mean by convergence here?

Comment: There is no sense in which this converges. It might have a Ramanujan sum value. And this assumes you mean to define half-factorials like $(1/2)!$ in terms of the Gamma function.

Comment: @lulu Many divergent series can be summed using one method or another and in most cases, all these methods end up agreeing. For instance, this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832501/the-divergent-sum-of-alternating-factorials) looks at a very similar problem.

Comment: @CalebBriggs the question specifically mentions “converges.” Ramanujan summation and related are not examples of convergence.

Comment: But those alternate methods of summation are not "convergence" which has a very well defined meaning.

Comment: @lulu I suppose the use of convergence might be nonstandard. I'm using it in the same way we might say the series that represents $\frac{1}{1-x}$  converges when $|x|>1$. The partial sums don't converge, but with a suitable definition of summation the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ can be made to converge in a wider domain. In this case for example, I'd consider the sum to "converge", but the partial sum method for adding terms is unsatisfactory.

Comment: For the purposes of asking a question to an audience you did not talk to previously so that you could introduce your nonstandard notation, you should IMO **not** call it convergent. The fruits can be seen already: you get an Answer telling you that the series does not converge (and, you and I both know that Greg has the full force of every mathematics authority on his side). Furthermore, divergent series questions on MSE that are not rigourously phrased tend to be downvoted and closed or even deleted. I would strongly suggest you rephrase.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I've taken your recommendation and rephrased the question. I personally believe it makes perfect sense to call these sums convergent as long one is willing to drop the notion of partial sums and replace it with something more robust--and I'm surprised more mathematicians aren't of this same opinion. Nonetheless, I'll leave that view out to make the question better.

Comment: +1'd on edit, hope an answer to the modified question comes along. I don't 100% share your belief but I won't elaborate in case it derails the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Borel-like resummation works:
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n (\alpha n)!}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} t^{\alpha n} dt} }  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n t^{\alpha n} } dt}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t} }}{{1 + t^\alpha  }}dt} .
$$

Comment: Wow-- this is very elegant! And it even works for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (\alpha n)! x^n$ too which is great!

Answer (score 1):

There is no nonzero value of $x$ for which $(-1)^n (\frac n\alpha)! x^n$ tends to $0$ with $n$, and so that power series will not converge anywhere but $x=0$. This fact means that taking $\alpha\to\infty$ isn't an option.